# using if statement and an asp.net control in a repeater

Tags: if-statement, eval, inline

I'm trying to use an asp.net controller in a asp.net repeater but I get error.here is my codeblock.

```
<td><% if ((bool)Eval("isMenu") == true)
{%><asp:ImageButton ImageUrl='/Panel/img/ok.png' ID='btn_aktif' OnClick='btn_aktif_Click' CommandArgument='<%Eval("KategoriID")%>' runat='server' />
<%}
else
{ %>
<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl='/Panel/img/ok.png' ID='btn_pasif' OnClick="btn_pasif_Click" CommandArgument='<%Eval("KategoriID")%>' runat='server' />
<%} %>
<td>
```

is there anyway to do that?

Comment: What error do you get? You also seem to be opening a `<td>` tag within a `<td>` tag

Comment: the error is: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Answer (score 1):

why do you need `==true` , `if ((bool)Eval("isMenu"))` is enough. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the hash symbol in your code `#` where you use Eval. For example, update to:

```
<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl='/Panel/img/ok.png' ID='btn_aktif' OnClick='btn_aktif_Click' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("KategoriID")%>' runat='server' />
```

So, use this code

```
{%><asp:ImageButton ImageUrl='/Panel/img/ok.png' ID='btn_aktif' OnClick='btn_aktif_Click' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("KategoriID")%>' runat='server' />
<%}
else
{ %>
<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl='/Panel/img/ok.png' ID='btn_pasif' OnClick="btn_pasif_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("KategoriID")%>' runat='server' />
<%} %>
```

Comment: still get the same error error shows that line "<% if ((bool)Eval("isMenu") == true)" and says Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <td><asp:ImageButton ImageUrl='/Panel/img/ok.png' Visible='<%# (bool) Eval("isMenu")==true? true:false%>' ID='ImageButton1' OnClick='btn_aktif_Click' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("KategoriID")%>' runat='server' />
<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl='/Panel/img/cancel.png' Visible='<%# (bool) Eval("isMenu")==true? false:true%>' ID='img_cancel' OnClick='btn_aktif_Click' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("KategoriID")%>' runat='server' /></td>
```

I used visible attribute to sove this problem